# Navigation is null in xamarin basepage inherited from content page

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a BasePage which is inherited from xamarin forms contentpage as below

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XLabs.Ioc;
using XLabs.Platform.Device;
using XLabs.Platform.Services;

namespace Sthotraani.Views
{
    public partial class BasePage : ContentPage
    {
        public IDevice XDevice;
        public BasePage()
        {
            XDevice = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>();
            EnsureConnection();
        }
    public async void  EnsureConnection()
    {
        if (XDevice.Network.InternetConnectionStatus() == NetworkStatus.NotReachable)
        {
            await Navigation.CheckNPushModal(new NoNetworkPage());
        }
    }

}
}
```

All remaining pages iherit from  this page, but due to null navigation this fails when there's no network connection. Please help.
Main page

```
    // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new SthotraaniMaster();
```

and xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sthotraani.Views;assembly=Sthotraani"
             x:Class="Sthotraani.Views.SthotraaniMaster" >



  <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage"  />
  </MasterDetailPage.Master>
  <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor="#00796B" BarTextColor="White"  >
      <x:Arguments>
        <local:GodsPage />
      </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
  </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

Master page is just menu, gods page is the content page which inherits from BasePage

```
public static async Task<Page> CheckNPopModal(this INavigation navigation, Page p)
    {
        Page  rp = null;
        if (navigation.ModalStack.Any(m => m.GetType() == p.GetType()))
        {
           rp = await navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
        }
        return rp;
    }

 public static async Task CheckNPushModal(this INavigation navigation, Page p)
    {
        if (!navigation.ModalStack.Any(m => m.GetType() == p.GetType()))
        {
            await navigation.PushModalAsync(p,true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the MainPage?

Comment: Can you show the exception that you get?

Comment: @Sanne it just says object reference not set to instance of an object when i debug i see Navigation inner is null

Comment: So it crashes on this line : await Navigation.CheckNPushModal(new NoNetworkPage()); and XDevice does have a value? If you try this: await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NoNetworkPage());

Comment: yes. both are same in that extension i just check the stack if there is a page already
public static async Task<Page> CheckNPopModal(this INavigation navigation, Page p)
        {
            Page  rp = null;
            if (navigation.ModalStack.Any(m => m.GetType() == p.GetType()))
            {
               rp = await navigation.PopModalAsync(true);
            }
            return rp;
        }

Comment: What is your code for CheckNPushModal() then?

Comment: That is the code for POP not PUSH in your code sample your using PUSH

Comment: @Sanne my mistake, edited the posted

Comment: Why are these static and are they trying to use this? When your static your this is always null?

Comment: try passing in your navigation instead of this like so: await Navigation.CheckNPushModal(navigation, new NoNetworkPage());

Comment: It's an extension method so finally navigation gets passed. This is just to say the method is an extension to INavigation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110995/discussion-between-sanne-and-kris).

Answer (score 0):

It's working after removing XLabs forms from my project. Now navigation is not null.